# Mink to run new instances of Selenium without having to manually run the standalone server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mink

I've worked with Cucumber and Watir before and, when I wanted to run a test in firefox, I just created a new browser instance the following way:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 60
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox , profile: $profile, :http_client => client
```

Now I am using Behat, and when I want to run a test in Firefox, I have to define the Selenium parameters in behat.yml first:

```
Behat\MinkExtension:
  base_url:  'http://test.com'
  sessions:
    default:
      goutte: ~
      javascript:
        selenium2:
          wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

But I also have to run the Selenium standalone server in a separate terminal window:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

And leave it running in background.

My question is: is there any way to make Mink work like Watir? Launching a new browser instance when a test is run and killing it after it finishes without having to worry about running the service in background?